# iOS App on sale, works great except in Hong Kong

Tags: ios, localization

I've made an iOS app for a client which is French at the origin, and localized it so it can display English if the phone is not french. Works great on my iphone (I've tested it with several langages).

My client (who is in Hong-Kong for showing the app...) told me that on the Hong-Kong's iPhones, the app crashes right after the Default screen. What could possibly cause that? I'm asking here because I have no idea about that. For info, I do implement the push notifications.

I'm sorry I don't have more info, but as I am not currently out there I can't have any log.

Has anyone had this problem before? Is it known that an app could work in certain countries and not in others?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to simulate the problem with your app changing:

1. Language preferences.
2. Region preferences.
3. App Store Apple ID to Apple ID with HK region (if you have implemented in-app purchases).
4. Changing time preferences to HK date and time.

Comment: Tried this, and working fine... I'm trying to get logs... I'm also hoping that it was a single case, but I'd like to understand! Not easy to work with a client at the other side of the planet :s But thanks for your time ! If you have any other idea, I'll take it !

Comment: Maybe your client uses a different iPhone version?

Answer (score 0):

If there are some country specific files present, which are loaded at run time based on country selection, then it is a possible scenario for the app to crash, as app will not able to find HK specific file(If some default file is not there.)

rest we can tell only after looking in to the logs, but above is the most probable scenario.

Comment: There is no specifi files loaded. There is just two localized files, one for french and one for english! Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @Ptitfilou - that is what i mean, might be your app is searching HK file for Hongkong which is not there, so it got crashed.

Comment: But the app works fine everywhere else, the primary langage is french and next its english, a friend of mine tried it in germany, he got english. If you want to try, the app is named "gardez le sourire" in french. http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gardez-le-sourire/id524079273?l=fr&ls=1&mt=8 I don't know where you're located, but it might help if you get the same bug !

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with my app where it was only crashing when Hong Kong was simulated as the location. The problem turned out to be that the `locality` property of `CLPlacemark` was being returned as `(null)`.

I didn't have a check for that and was setting an attributed string based on the locality value returned, therefore causing the app to crash.